# Sequelize with LIKE in DATE column

Tags: date, sequelize.js

Im trying to get all the high scores for today, but the database has DATETIME as type. Code:

```
let date_time = new Date();
let date = date_time.getDate();  
let month = date_time.getMonth() +1 +""; //jan is 0.
if (month.length == 1){
  month="0"+month;
}
let year = date_time.getFullYear();
let theDate = year+"-"+month+"-"+date;
let d = new Date(theDate);
console.log(theDate);
console.log(theDate);

stat_db.findAll({
  order: [['date', 'DESC']],
  limit: 10,
  where: {
    date: {
      [Op.like]: '%theDate'}
  }
})
```

Output is

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments: 
>   [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: %theDate, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
>   Error
>
> Executing (default): SELECT `username`, `date`, `matches_played`, `high_score` FROM `stats` AS `stat` WHERE `stat`.`date` LIKE 'Invalid date' ORDER BY `stat`.`date` DESC LIMIT 10;

Comment: `LIKE` is for string values, not for dates in SQL.

Comment: Okay! How should I do this?

Comment: Consider you want to get score for 2019-03-01 then create two params 1) startDt with 2019-03-01 00:00:00 2) 2019-03-01 25:59:59 and use between operator and rest is only sorting and paging

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using greater than (start of today) since I only wanted the games for today.